# Why do many sports teams seem to wear white jerseys when they play a home game?

Tags: equipment, uniform

Why do sports teams like baseball, football, and basketball wear white uniforms when they play a home game?

Comment: Related to http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15610/how-is-it-decided-in-hockey-which-team-wears-white-or-colored-jersey

Answer (score 5):

> Why do sports teams like baseball, football, and basketball wear white uniforms when they play a home game?

In short, because they're addressed in the rules. More practically, it's to distinguish two teams from one another.

---

For the MLB, the home team wearing white uniforms may be required based on the league said team is in. This is addressed in Rule 3.03(d) of the [2016 MLB rulebook](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf):

> A league may provide that each team shall
>   wear a distinctive uniform at all times, or that each team shall
>   have two sets of uniforms, **white for home games** and a different
>   color for road games.

For the NBA, although the home team wearing white uniforms is not a requirement, it does require said team to wear light-colored uniforms. This is addressed in Rule 3, Section VI of the [2015-2016 NBA Rulebook](https://turnernbahangtime.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/official-nba-rule-book-2015-16.pdf):

> The **home team shall wear light color jerseys**, and the visitors dark
>   jerseys unless otherwise approved. For neutral court games and
>   doubleheaders, the second team named in the official schedule shall be
>   regarded as the home team and shall wear the light colored jerseys.

For the FIBA, although the home team wearing white uniforms is not a requirement, it does require said team to wear light-colored uniforms (and explicitly prefers white). This is addressed in Rule 4.3.3 of the [2014 FIBA Rules of the Game](http://www.fiba.com/en/Module/c9dad82f-01af-45e0-bb85-ee4cf50235b4/1faaa885-7478-4f87-ae5a-45b2c5939e96):

> The first team named in the programme **(home team) shall wear light-coloured
>   shirts (preferably white)**.

For the IFAB, the home team wearing white (or light-colored) uniforms is not a requirement. However, it does require both teams to wear distinct colors from one another. This is addressed in Law 4, Section 3 of the [2016-2017 IFAB Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/79/92/44/laws.of.the.game.2016.2017_neutral.pdf):

> The two teams must wear colours that distinguish them from each other
>   and the match officials

Comment: I will update to the [most recent set of rules/laws](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/664) where necessary.